# Stepper Angular 5|6 HTML CSS Onclick Event

Tags: html, css, angular, progress, stepper

I need help with click event to my stepper progress.

for example i 'am on Step 1 when i click on 3 i ll move to Step 3

i tried with click on `<li>` but doesn't work

Here is my html and CSS

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 block border">
    <div class="wrapper-progressBar">
      <ul class="progressBar">
        <li class="active"></li>
        <li class=""></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper-progressBar {
  width: 100%
}

.progressBar {
counter-reset: step;
}

.progressBar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 21%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.progressBar li:before {
  cursor:pointer;
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  background-color: white
}

.progressBar li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressBar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressBar li.active {
  color: green;
}

.progressBar li.active:before {
  border-color: green;
  background-color: white;
}

.progressBar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kingstore/jL6qyft1/3/

"I expect this "

[image]

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-stepper-single-form?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.html

Comment: Thank you for answer but i am using Angular 5|6 not Angular Material

Comment: I have the same concern, Angular material is providing all functionality which we need in step form but with bootstrap only it might looks hard to do.

Comment: where's your Angular code you've tried?

Comment: @MedDiv I found one github project , I think it is exactly as we want . https://github.com/cwun/angular-multi-step-wizard

Comment: i think I have almost the solution  but  i ll see this project  thanks @Arjun

Comment: @MedDiv Hi, I am running throw same issue can you help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the (click) event binding.

Something like this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 block border">
    <div class="wrapper-progressBar">
      <ul class="progressBar">
        <li *ngFor="let n of number" [ngClass]="active" (click)="onActive()"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this: https://angular.io/guide/user-input